# Why is "/" not owned by root during Azure Pipelines builds?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to debug why snaps do not run on Azure pipelines builds, and what I have found is that "/" is not owned by root during these builds, it is owned by uid 500 (not 0).

Does anybody know why "/" is not owned by root? Is this a bug with Azure Pipelines?

For example the following example does not work:

```
pr:
- 1.*

jobs:
- job: ldc2_snap
  timeoutInMinutes: 0
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-16.04
  steps:
  - script: |
      set -x
      snap version
      lxd --version
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo snap install --classic --candidate snapcraft
      export PATH="${PATH}:/snap/bin"
      snapcraft --version
      snapcraft
    displayName: Build ldc2 snap package
```

This fails because snap-confine (which is run by snapcraft / snapd) won't run if "/" is not owned by root. We (snapd developers) do not want to allow snap-confine to run with non-root owned "/" without understanding why this is the case, as it seems like a bug with Azure Pipelines.

Comment: Hi @Ian Johnson Did you tried agent ubuntu-18.04? How did it go?

Comment: This bug was eventually resolved upstream, see https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/681

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to run your pipeline on agent **ubuntu-18.04**.  I can reproduce the same issue with agent ubuntu-16.04. But the issue seems gone on agent ubuntu-18.04.

If you want to configure your own self-hosted agent. You can refer to the detailed steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Yes, as per this github issue it was eventually resolved for all ubuntu images, see https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/681

Answer (score 0):

Agents run out of a working directory (defined by the system variable `Pipeline.Workspace` / environment variable `PIPELINE_WORKSPACE`). You only have access to that working directory on the hosted agent. It's not a bug, it's an intentional limitation.

If you need something to access the root of the file system, provision your own private agents.

Comment: But what about installing software like with `sudo apt-get`? That accesses files outside of the working directory and works fine, it's just that snaps can't run if "/" is not owned by root (and there is a good security reason for this, see https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/permissions-problem-using-snapcraft-in-azure-pipelines/13258/13)